# Using repositories in services, and services in controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I program in such a way that I avoid using services in other services https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/core/jpa/service. I try to use only repositories on services. I am currently writing a controller that uses two services. One to save files in the cloud, and the other to save from the entity with the file identifier in the cloud.

```
    @PutMapping(value = "/contributions/{id}/photos")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public
void updatePhotoContribution(
        @PathVariable("id") final Long id,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Set<Long> elementIdsToAdd,
        @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> elementsToAdd,
        @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> newElementsToAdd,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Set<Long> idsToUpdate,
        @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> elementsToUpdate,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Set<Long> idsToDelete,
        @RequestParam final Set<String> sources,
        @RequestParam(required = false) final String comment
) {
    Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();

    for(files) {
        String id = this.storageService.save(...); // Save the file in the cloud with file identifiers stored in the cloud
        ids.add(id);
    }

    Contribution contribution = //create contribution

    try {
        this.movieContributionPersistenceService.updateReviewContribution(contribution, id, this.authorizationService.getUserId());
    } catch(ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        //  remove the file from the cloud
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
    } catch(ResourceConflictException e) {
        //  remove the file from the cloud
        throw new ResourceConflictException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is the only solution to the problem that occurred to me. If I used storageService in movieContributionPersistenceService, it would look better, but I stick to the fact that I use only repositories on services. What do you think about it?

That's the other controller that I created earlier on the same principle: https://pastebin.com/Ry1gcYdL

Comment: I think that sticking to absolute, arbitrary design principles works... until it fails. Just do what is needed in the way you judge is the better.

Comment: Even though this might be an interesting question to ask, it's not suitable for Stack Overflow. Make sure to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Its not a catastrophic structure to autowire service inside another service but in that way you will end up coupling your services which could lead to maintenance problems.

instead of coupling your services you can create a util with the common functionality and make both of the service use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is design principal how you want to follow in your application,

1. You could have dependencies of other services in the service class
2. You could use only next layer of classes which is repositories in your case.

If you go by option 1, please keep in mind that you could end up having circular reference in your spring boot application.
For example,  You may end up something like

Service A -> Service B -> Service A

Starting from spring boot 2.6.0 circular reference is prohibited, [Spring Circular reference is Prohibited by Default.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6.0-M2-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default)

So it is better to have a common service class to avoid circular reference, or else keep the correct hierarchy of services when using other service reference.